# JS + Ajax + Thymeleaf - Accessing JS value from thymeleaf context

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

I'm wondering if there's a way to access a JavaScript object from within thymeleaf's inline syntax.

I'm trying to build a URL using the `[[@{}]]` syntax in JavaScript. However, inside of the URL, I need to get access to a JS variable.

Here's the code:

```
var fieldPathStr = /*[[@{{lessonId}/questions/{questionId}(lessonId=${lesson.id}, questionId=question.id)}]]*/"1/questions/2";
```

Specifically, it's the `question.id` that is the JS variable, but it (obviously) just creates the final URL as:

`1/questions/question.id`

Is there a way to structure this assignment statement so that I can get the actual value of `question.id` and have it evaluate it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract values like this:

```
var lessonId = [[${lesson.id}]];
var questionId = [[${question.id}]];
```

but I am not sure that it is a way to go. If you are working with the lists, you would need to extract them in js which means twice the work on the machine side...
There is a way to do it, but probably little different than what you thought! 
An example of how I managed my popup box to confirm removal of item from the list:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function deleteObject(id) {
        bootbox.confirm([[#{msg.ask}]], function(result) {
            if (result) {
                var url = /*[[ @{'/admin/vozila/izbrisi?vin='} ]]*/ "genericUrl";
                url = url+id;
                document.location = url;
            }
        }); 
    };
</script>
```

Once this is done, all you need is to call it and pass the object id:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#" th:onclick="'javascript:deleteObject(\'' + ${vozilo.vin} + '\');'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i><span th:text="#{rad.obr}">Radnja - izbrisi</span></a>
```

So you are not getting thymeleaf rendered inside js, but you pass the values to the function when called.
I guess in your case it would look something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
function callLink(lessonID, questionID){
var fieldPathStr = lessonID+/*[[@{'/questions/'}]]*/"1/questions/2";
var finalStr = lessonID+fieldPathStr+questionID;
};
</script>
```

where questionID, and lessonID should look like this:

```
<a href="#" th:onclick="'javascript:callLink(\'' + ${lesson.id} + '\', \'' + ${question.id} + '\');'"></a>
```

Hope this works for you?

Comment: Yeah that will probably work. I'm not sure why I didn't think to just populate the ID afterwards, pretty easy fix... silly me

Comment: We've all been there! :D